# Find the length of the array that was passed to you in Q#

Tags: arrays, variable-length-array, q#, qubit

I have an operation as follows to which the driver needs to send an array of qubits.

```
operation myOp(qubits: Qubit[]) : () {
     // uses elements from the qubit array        
 }
```

How do I find the length of this array from within the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let n = Length(qubits)
```

This will store the length in the variable n. Also n is a constant which can't be changed. If for any reason you want a mutable variable n then

```
mutable n = Length(qubits)
```

which can be changed. Now you can iterate through the array using a for loop (works for both constant or mutable n)

```
for(index in 0 .. (n-1)) {
//process the element qubits[index]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Length(qubits)`

It is mentioned in the documentation on numeric expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-qr-expressions#numeric-expressions